# Improve scroll performance on my website

Tags: html, css, scroll

We just launched our new one-page website, but the performance of the scroll is really bad, especially on old browsers.

Do you have any idea of how I could improve it ?

This is the URL : http://butterflyeffect.fr

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome Devtools you can generate a CSS profile.
I did that and I see lots of time at
img, * and sponsor items.

But in my experience and looking at your (great) site, the lag is probably in the opacity things. So if you have some background and overlaying parts that partly are see through, that is lagging. I would copy your whole site, and just kill your css, remove a lot and constantly check when the performance comes back. Begin with removing all the background images and not fully opaque elements.

Also a nice video
http://vimeo.com/54990931

But to be honest I don't fully agree with adjusting, I think its up to browser vendors to improve their algoritms. But it doesn't mind learning the basics and just think about it while building.

regards